# Asp.net SitePathMap with multiple routes

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

I have a web site with two routes. Basically the user can do one of the following:

Project -> Iteration -> Story

or

Project -> Story

I have two .sitemap files to accomodate the two different routes (as two nodes cannot exist with the same name) however when I browse the site and move from the iteration page to the story page, it only shows the map path for Project to story.

Does anyone have an ideas on how to do Routing with SitePathMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by programmatically changing the sitemap provider depending on the previous SiteMapNode.